# Method overriding and overloading

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding, overloading

I have the code listed below. Why does it print: "V" - "greet(Z)" - "greet(Z)"?  I would have said "V" - "greet(V)" - "greet(Z)" but it seems that I'm missing some points on method overloading and overriding, can someone explain me and/or link some resources to master this?

```
class Z {

    public void me() {
        System.out.print(" Z");

    }

    public void greet(Z z) {
        System.out.print ("greet(Z)");
    }

}
class V extends Z {

    @Override
    public void me() {
        System.out.println("V");
    }

    public void greet(V v) {
        System.out.println("greet(V)");
    }
}
public  class Quiz{
    public  static void main(String[] args) {

        Z a = new V();
        V b = new V();
        a.me();
        System.out.print("-");
        a.greet(b);
        System.out.print("-");
        a.greet(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your misunderstanding is about declaration and instantiation, not about overriding/overloading. a is declared as type Z, not type V.

Comment: I know this, but when i use the method a.greet(b) why it uses the greet method  from  Z. Wasn't this supposed to use the dynamic type method?

Comment: `a` is an object of type `Z` , and ONLY of type `Z` , there is no possible overriden method to call there.

Comment: @karalis1 as I said in my first comment: a is declared as being of type Z, not of type B. So it is using what it should be using.

Comment: you override `me()` because its signature is fully copied, but overload `great()` because different argument type is used. So `a.great(...)` is called on class `Z` always printing "greet(Z)" regardless value passed

Comment: "A child class can redefine the instance methods of its parent class. This is called method overriding. **The signature (return type, parameter type, the number of parameters, and order of parameters) must be the same as defined in the parent class.** Method overriding is done to achieve runtime polymorphism."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public void greet(V v)` is an overloaded version of `public void greet(Z z)`: the former **does not override** the latter.

```
a.greet(b);
```

`a` is of type `Z`, there is only one method to choose from: `greet(Z z)`.

```
a.greet(a);
```

`a` is of type `Z`, there is still only one method to choose from: `greet(Z z)`.

```
b.greet(a);
```

`b` is of type `V`, there are two methods to choose from. Since `a` is of type `Z`, the most appropriate `greet(Z z)` will be chosen.

```
b.greet(b);
```

`b` is of type `V`, there are two methods to choose from. Since `b` is of type `V`, the most appropriate `greet(V V)` will be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize

```
  V b = new V();
```

b has a reference of V and object is created of type V
so when u call

```
 a.greet(b);
```

It will first look into V class that is accepting parameter of type V.

But in the first line

```
Z a = new V();
```

You are creating object of V but the type is Z.So when calling

```
a.greet(b);
```

will only accept the type Z. Because the the greet method in V is overloaded to accept type V.